# Window appears and blocks debugging (lldb vscode windows) but works fine on command line apps

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, clang, glfw, lldb

I am making a gui app with glfw and debugging works fine until window is created... Then it just becomes an unresponsive black window... I cant even alt tab or use task manager. It wont even let me go to other tabs like my browser. I have to alt tab and close vs code

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "LLDB",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app/maze.exe",
        }
    ]
}
```

I build separately as im new to c++. I dont think this should affect it? The app directory does have .ilk and .pdb files

```
@echo off

set output_path=..\app\
set output_file=maze

:: Compile resource script
::if exist resources.res ( del /F resources.res )
::rc.exe /fo resources.res resources.rc

cd ../ 
clang++ -g -o %output_path%%output_file%.exe -std=c++17 -I. -Ilibs -Ilibs/imgui main.cpp libs/imgui/*.cpp -Llibs -Llibs/GL -Llibs/GLFW -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmsvcrt -lshell32 -lglew32s -DGLEW_STATIC -lglu32 -llibcmt -lole32 -lwinmm -mwindows build/resources.res

cd %output_path% & if exist %output_file% ( start /B %output_file% )
```

Spent a few hours trying to figure it out, hopefully its a simple fix?